# Livewire validate each array item using different rules

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-10

Let's say I have a collection/array of services. Each service has a type  (flights, hotels, movies, etc...) and depending on it's type there is a list of required fields to be filled. Now, Laravel permit's me do the validation using dynamic rules() method:

```
function rules(){
    $rules = [];
    foreach($this->services as $index => $service){
        switch ($service->type){
            case 'flight': {
                $rules["services.{$index}.flight_number"] = 'string|requred';
                $rules["services.{$index}.departure_date"] = 'date|requred';
                // etc.
                break;
            }
            case 'movie': {
                $rules["services.{$index}.movie_name"] = 'string|requred';
                $rules["services.{$index}.seat"] = 'int|requred';
                // etc.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

BUT for Livewire it doesn't work - for Livewire to detect these fields, it looks like I **must** use `.*.` instead of the `.{$index}.`
So how can I define different rules for each element of collection/array for Livewire?

Comment: In livewire you can define a `rules()` method, this should work exactly the same as the laravel validation. But you will need to call the $this->validate() on the livewire component when you need to validate the items, it doesn't work automatically with a live property when you use the rules() method, see: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/validation#defining-a-rules-method